# getting incomplete xml code using rest in android

Tags: android, web-services, restlet

I'm calling the openNMS webservices to my android mobile using restlet framework. Iam getting the resource but not complete.Its getting only limited number of xml elements. I'm calling the web service using

```
  final String url = "http://172.16.3.32:8980/opennms/rest/outages?limit=20";
       Log.d(TAG, "url = " + url);
                ClientResource resource = new ClientResource(url);
       resource.setChallengeResponse(new ChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, "admin", "admin"));

   Log.d(TAG, "getting resource");
   resource.get();
   rep = resource.get();
 Log.v(TAG, "get res rep"+ rep.getText().toString());
```

Am i missing anything??

Comment: Log truncates the output, are you determining that its incomplete based just on teh log output ?

Comment: no iam even parsing the resource using sax parser and getting only a few of the information parsed.

Comment: @superfell I guess you are right, Iam displaying the output in listviw which is not setting all the values parsed.How could i see all the data received before parsing other than using log.w()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry folks,

It was all right. The log couldn't display all the xml content and i missed something in my code which stopped parsing in the middle.

Thanks for the response.